# How to Make Mongoose's .populate() work with an embedded schema/subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, populate

I read up that you can make Mongoose auto [pouplate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) ObjectId fields. However I am having trouble structuring a query to populate fields in a subdoc.

My models:

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question_text: String,
    type: String,
    comment_field: Boolean,
    core_question: Boolean,
    identifier: String
});

var SurveyQuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question_number: Number,
    question: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question', required: true} //want this popuplated
});

var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    start_date: Date,
    end_date: Date,
    title: String,
    survey_questions: [SurveyQuestionSchema]
});
```

Right now I achieve the effect by doing:

```
Survey.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
    if(err || !data) { return handleError(err, res, data); }

    var len = data.survey_questions.length;
    var counter = 0;

    var data = data.toJSON();

    _.each(data.survey_questions, function(sq){
        Question.findById(sq.question, function(err, q){
            sq.question = q;

            if(++counter == len) {
                res.send(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Which obviously is a very error-prone way of doing it...

Comment: Found a [bug thread](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/601) and a [roadmap](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/1292) for this issue.  Both current.

Comment: Thanks @numbers1311407! Great to know. I'm starting to think though that there must be a way I can reorganize my schema to make it work with current implementation though.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question (as I have no knowledge of the app beyond this), but do you really need `SurveyQuestion`?  Mongoose array order is guaranteed, so you don't need to sort them.  Looking at it with no knowledge of the app, it lools like `Survey` could just embed `Question`s.

Comment: Well the idea was that later on SurveyQuestion can have some modifier fields like required and maybe an array of attributes which EXTEND onto the Question

Comment: By the way for context, here is the corresponding [backbone models](https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder/blob/master/app/js/survey-builder/models.js) and [mongoose models](https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder-api-server/blob/master/schemas.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted in the comments above, this is an issue currently under scrutiny by the mongoose team (not yet implemented).

Also, looking at your problem from an outsider's perpsective, my first thought would be to change the schema to eliminate `SurveyQuestion`, as it has a very relational db "join" model feel.  Mongoose embedded collections have a static sort order, eliminating the need for keeping a positional field, and if you could handle question options on the `Survey` itself, it would reduce the schema complexity so you wouldn't need to do the double-populate.

That being said, you could probably reduce the queries down to 2, by querying for all the questions at once, something like:

```
Survey.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
    if(err || !data) { return handleError(err, res, data); }

    var data = data.toJSON();
    var ids = _.pluck(data.survey_questions, 'question');

    Question.find({_id: { $in: ids } }, function(err, questions) {
        _.each(data.survey_questions, function(sq) {
            sq.question = _.find(questions, function(q) { 
                var id = q._id.toString();
                return id == sq.question; 
            });

        });
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Ended up using your code, but made a few edits (edited your response).